# Mixing strings and html links in react/typescript constants

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im trying to mix a string and a link, within an attribute of one variable :

```
const News = [
  {
    headline: 'some headline',
    text:
      "some text" + <a href='url'> click me </a>,
  },
];
```

Im displaying News on another page, when I access the text via **news.text** though I get following output

```
some text[object Object]
```

---

Following code works fine

```
const News = [
      {
        headline: 'some headline',
        text:
          <a href='url'> click me </a>,
      },
    ];
```

I have read similar questions, they were quite what I was looking for, since I feel like there has to be a simple solution for this small problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if your las example works for you, maybe you could try something like this:

```
const News = [
  {
    headline: 'some headline',
    text: <span>Some text <a href='url'> click me </a></span>,
  },
];
```

I haven't tested, but is just an idea.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This is handful when mixing HTML tags with variables:

```
 <li className="row"><strong> Alerts: </strong> <br/>  {`${user.alerts}`} </li>
```